# CPU and GPU Stress test for Nvidia Jetson Xavier (Ubuntu 18.04, Jetpack 4.6)

Tags: nvidia, stress-testing, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano, jetson-xavier

How can I make a simultaneous CPU and GPU stress test on Jetson Xavier machine (Ubuntu 18.04, Jetpack 4.6)?
The only code found is
https://github.com/JTHibbard/Xavier_AGX_Stress_Test with tough package incompatibility issues. It only works for CPU.
Anyone can contribute with providing another code or solve the issue with the mentioned one? A python code is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found. For CPU stress test, the above link works. It needs `numba` package to be installed. For GPU stress test, the samples in cuda folder of the Nvidia Jetson machines can be simply and efficiently used. The samples are in the `/usr/local/cuda/samples`. Choose one and compile it using `sudo make`. The compiled test file will be accessible in `/usr/local/cuda/samples/bin/aarch64/linux/release` (aarch64 may differ in different architectures). Run the test and check the performances using `sudo jtop` in another command line.